# ng-repeat loop more than the number of elements

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to implement `ng-repeat` with `ng-style`. It works perfectly. However, I do not understand why my method is called more than the number of elements in my `ng-repeat`!

Do you know why?

To complete my explanation, I created a : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UNEjb/2/)

Comment: How do you know how many times your function was called?

Comment: When i do an `alert` or a `console.log` in my function.

Comment: i have try to put an alert for the items.length and nothing goes wrong, you have 5 elements.

Comment: i put a console log into style function and it indeed seems that ng-repeat is run twice. As to why check the answer.

Comment: @Silas Did you gain understanding from any of the answers? Do you have any unresolved issues or questions? If so ask, if not then accept whatever was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think that when your html code is compiled, it executes ng-style directive even if there is no data (when items == null). After that your controller changes $scope.items, forcing other calls to $scope.getStyle().

I think if you put a ng-if="items != null" within ng-repeat, your function will be called only 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

Solution looks fine. The reason for multiple calls is angular digest loop. You can read about it here: http://www.benlesh.com/2013/08/angularjs-watch-digest-and-apply-oh-my.html

It works by running the loop and looking if the values changed for the watches. When they stabilize it ends. You can have multiple passes of the event loop in angular app and that is pretty normal. The limit is set afaik for 10 iterations. If bindings do not stabilize then exception is thrown.

Additional reading, highly recommended:
http://teropa.info/blog/2013/11/03/make-your-own-angular-part-1-scopes-and-digest.html
Part Keep Digesting While Dirty is the answer to your question i believe.

So it is by design.